# Laptop not playing sound through headphones

Tags: laptop, audio, headphones

Realtek is recognising when the headphones are being plugged in, and the sound is being muted from the main speakers, but the sound isn't being pushed through the headphones.

I've verified that the headphones are working, and I've also tried it with other headphones to the same result. I've scanned for window updates, and there's been no change. There's also the same issue on Xubuntu, which is installed as a separate partition on the same laptop.

It's a Scan 3xs laptop, with windows 8.1 and XUbuntu installed. It's about a week old, although I'd not tried to use the headphones previously. The fact that the port recognises that something's being plugged in makes me think that it's a software issue. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Same problem - Scan 3XS Laptop - upgraded from Win8.1 Home to Win 10 Pro.  Device Manager shows everything is okay (Intel Display Audio & VIA HD Audio(Win8.1))  Installed audio drivers from DVD. No cigar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to unrelated issues, I wound out doing a completely clean reinstall of the operating system so that I could upgrade to windows 10. This fixed the problem. Something of a nuclear option, but can't argue with the results.